# How to Comments code in shopify?

Tags: shopify

How do I add comments to code in **shopify**?  Is this correct?

`{% comment %}
code
{% endcomment %}`

Answer (score 0):

use it to comment in shopify

`{% comment %}
code
{% endcomment %}`